# Initialize state with a Spring TestExecutionListener before JUnit rules run

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I want to initialize state before each Spring Boot JUnit test case with a `TestExecutionListener`. This initialization needs to run *before* the respective callback of JUnit `@Rule`s is called.

I would have expected that the `beforeTestMethod` would be right for this because its JavaDoc comment says

> Pre-processes a test *before* execution of *before* lifecycle callbacks of the underlying test framework

Rules contribute "before" callbacks to a test, so I would have expected that `beforeTestMethod` is executed before the rule. However, the debugger shows that this is not the case!

---

This is the structure of my code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = MyTestExecutionListener.class, mergeMode = MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    @Rule
    public MyRule rule;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        // ...
    }

    // ... more tests
}
```

```
public class MyTestExecutionListener implements TestExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class AutoLogin extends ExternalResource {

    @Override
    protected void before() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want the methods to execute in the order

- `beforeTestMethod()`
- `rule.before()`
- `test1()`

but the actual order is

- `rule.before()`
- `beforeTestMethod()`
- `test1()`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or which other `TestExecutionListener` method I should use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to initialise the state for every test just before the `Rule` is executed, you should use the `prepareTestInstance` method of the `TestExecutionListener` interface.

```
@Override
public void prepareTestInstance(TestContext testContext) {
    System.out.println("inside prepareTestInstance");
}
```

That way you will have the methods executed in below order:

- `prepareTestInstance()`
- `rule.before()`
- `test1()`

Do note that `prepareTestInstance` will be executed **before every test method**